# JavaFX Browser - display entry's getTitle() in ListView

Tags: listview, javafx, observablelist

I`m need to add a display history functionality to my JavaFX web browser. 
I have:
method to get History as ObservableList:

```
public static ObservableList<Entry> getHistoryList() {
    WebHistory history = MyJavaFXBrowser.getWebEngine().getHistory();
    ObservableList<Entry> entries = history.getEntries();
    return entries; 
}
```

and to convert to ListView

```
public static ListView<Entry> getHistoryPane() {
    return new ListView<Entry>(getHistoryList());
}
```

How can I only display Entry.getTitle() - not the full information.
[image]

If I change my method to this:

```
public static ObservableList<String> getHistoryListTitles(){
        WebHistory history = MyJavaFXBrowser.getWebEngine().getHistory();
        ObservableList<Entry> entries = history.getEntries();
        ObservableList<String> titles = FXCollections.observableArrayList();;
        for (Entry entry: entries) {
            titles.add(entry.getTitle());
        }

        return titles;
    }
```

it does not update history when I change the page automatically.

How can I access method of the ObservableList in ListView?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a cell factory:

```
public static ListView<Entry> getHistoryPane() {
    ListView<Entry> historyPane = new ListView<Entry>(getHistoryList());

    historyPane.setCellFactory(lv -> new ListCell<Entry>() {
        @Override
        protected void updateItem(Entry entry, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(entry, empty);
            setText(entry == null ? null : entry.getTitle());
        }
    });

    return historyPane ;
}
```